# Pulling a list of users group membership through AzureAD with Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I'm working to pull a list of users from AzureAD that shows the users name and all the groups they are affiliated with. Below is the code I am using:

```
$output = @()

$Users = get-azureaduser -top 10 | select objectid,displayname

foreach($User in $users){

$group = Get-AzureADUserMembership -object $user.ObjectId | select displayname

$properties = [pscustomobject] @{
    "user name" = $user.displayname
    "Group" = $group.displayname

       }


write-host "got $properties"
  
  $output += $properties

 }

$output |export-csv "C:\users\USER\testing1234.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The output will only show "All Users" group and "system.object[]" for all others. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: good morning. You don't have to throw it into an array, you can pipe `$properties` directly into the csv using `-Append` .

Comment: Try this on the `PSCustomObject` `"Group" = $group.displayname | Out-String`

Comment: The out-string solved my "system.object[]" issue but its still only showing one group per user when they are members of multiple groups

Comment: When you say "showing" are you referring to PS Host or Excel? Groups is a multiline string, to see the groups you'll have to use `-Wrap` with `Format-Table` or double click the cell to see all the groups......

Comment: I'm talking about in excel. It is only pulling one group per user rather than ALL the groups that each user is in. Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you try expanding the Excel rows or double clicking on one cell of the 'Groups' column?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes it was wrapped in column, nice catch lol

So the results i'm trying to get is to list a users membership per line rather than bunch it up in one cell. Any thoughts?